# Writing words on the screen while php code is running

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I write the following cycl code:

```
$i = 1;
while($i <= 100){
  echo "$i\n";
  $i++;
}
```

This code is up to 100 internal memory. Up to 100, the screen will print up to 100 characters. That is, numbers are displayed on the screen after the code is being processed. I would like these numbers to be displayed during code execution. How can I do that?
(Someone told me it was possible to do this with ajax)

Comment: PHP runs on the server and the results are returned to the browser in one go, so yes, it will execute that loop and you will get all the results at the same time.  If you want to do this in the browser then you don't need PHP at all - you can do it completely in Javascript.  Are you really trying to get the numbers 1-100 showing in the browser, or is there something else you're trying to do?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question, because you're speaking about ajax. Did you try to add flush(); just after $i++; ? https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.flush.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use flush and sleep.

flush - send current buffer to client

sleep - wait time in seconds

```
$i = 1;
while($i <= 100){
    echo "$i\n";
    flush();
    $i++;
    sleep(1);
}
```

Comment: bro, i use this in  foreach but its work and print answer

Answer (score 1):

I'm here newbie, but at least want to try to help you.

Have you tried `ob_flush();` or `flush();` and `ob_clean();` in PHP to output buffer immediately?

Hope, that will help you somehow.

Have a nice day!